# Unfurling-Safe Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, source-layout

Write a [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine?answertab=votes#tab-top) **containing at least one newline/linefeed** whose every unfurling is either itself a proper quine or outputs the original quine. Your answer can mix and match outputting itself and outputting the original quine.

## Unfurlings

Unfurlings consist of:

1. Appending spaces to make the input a rectangle.
2. Taking all lines above the bottom one and rotating them a quarter-turn clockwise about the lower-right corner so that the right edge is on the same level as the bottom edge.
3. Repeat step (2) until the string is a single line to find all unfurlings.

For example, the first unfurling of

```
GFE
HID
ABC
```

is

```
   HG
   IF
ABCDE
```

and the rest are

```
   HG
   IF
ABCDE

     IH
ABCDEFG

       I
ABCDEFGH

ABCDEFGHI
```

This process is automated with [this program](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0LZDC/Wcol0Or9VzOrz20G4dJV0FMFTSObQkNOjQsnPbju5NiDi8RvP/fyUlJW8uRycgBQA) adapted from Emigna's answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139967/68261),where each step of unfurling in the output is delimited by a dashed line.

## Example

For example, if you have a program

```
K
AB
```

(no trailing spaces)

then it must be a proper quine and print itself(`'K\nAB'`, where `\n` represents a linefeed/newline).
According to the output of the unfurling program, we see that the next step in unfurling is

```
  K
AB
```

(note trailing space)

This must either print itself(`'  K\nAB '`) or the original program (`'K\nAB'`).
The next step in the unfurling is

```
AB K
```

This must either print itself (`'AB K'`), or the original program(`'K\nAB'`).

The byte-count of this program is `4` (`K`, `\n`, `A`, `B`).

## Score

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply, as usual.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139796/59487).

Comment: I think you could prevent easy answers by instead unfurling onto a new line instead of the last line of the program. However, I'm not sure the challenge is even possible at that point, but it may be.

Comment: If our answer has several unfurling steps, do they all have to print the original/themselves, or can some print themselves and some the original?

Comment: @MartinEnder The answer can mix and match printing the original and printing themselves.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
_='\n_=%r;print(_%%_,end="")';print(_%_,end="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/nyveVj0mL95Wtci6oCgzr0QjXlU1Xic1L8VWSUlTHS4GF/r/HwA)

I mean, it works :p

Comment: ಠ_____________ಠ

Comment: Can't you golf this down to just one line, `_='_=%r;print(_%%_)';print(_%_)
`? It contains "at least one newline/linefeed" (at the end)

Comment: @L3viathan then [the unfurlings](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0LZDC/Wcol0Or9VzOrz20G4dJV0FMFTSObQkNOjQsnPbju5NiDi8RvP/fyUlpXhb9Zi8eFvVIuuCosy8Eo14VdV4ndS8FFslJU11uBhciAuoBQA "05AB1E – Try It Online") go crazy :/

Comment: @dzaima I see...

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
_='\n_=%r;print(end=_%%_)';print(end=_%_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/nyveVj0mL95Wtci6oCgzr0QjNS/FNl5VNV5THUUgXvP/fwA)

Comment: Is this really distinct enough from dzaima's answer to warrant a new one? To me, this seems simply to be golfed a little.

Comment: @fireflame241 I think it deserves its own answer, plus I've written it on my own (not golfed his)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
_="\n_=%p;print _%%_";print _%_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/nyveVikmL95WtcC6oCgzr0QhXlU1XgnOjv//HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

OK, let's go with the obvious trivial solution.  At least it's shorter than the Python and Ruby solutions that use the same trick.

```
{N\"_~"}_~
```

This code begins with a newline, which is ignored by the CJam interpreter.  All the actual code is on the last line, which is not changed by the unfurling process.  The extra spaces and newlines introduced by unfurling the empty first line are also ignored by the interpreter.

Otherwise this is just a trivial tweak of a (or perhaps *the*) standard CJam quine.  `{N\"_~"}` defines a code block, `_~` makes a copy of it and executes it.  Inside the code block, `N\` pushes a newline before the copy of the block on the stack and `"_~"` pushes the string `_~` after it.  When the program ends, the CJam interpreter automatically prints everything on the stack, i.e. the newline, the code block and the `_~`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/n6vaL0Ypvk6pNr7u/38A)