# Cardinal Code Challenge

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

### Task

You're in charge of making a compass, of sorts.

Imagine your source code as the compass "needle" where running at different orientations produces distinct output.

Supported source code orientations are North, East, South, and West.

### Example

Let's say you have source code:

```
ABCD
 J K
WXYZ
```

We'll consider this the North orientation, rotating 90 degrees clockwise points us to the East:

```
W A
XJB
Y C
ZKD
```

rotating again points South:

```
ZYXW
K J 
DCBA
```

and finally, the last rotation to the West:

```
DKZ
C Y
BJX
A W
```

When ran, each of the above code examples should output a single, distinct [printable ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) character of your choosing.

### Notes

Your code shall take no input.

Empty spaces or new lines do not collapse/disappear when rotating.

Leading/trailing new lines are okay in output.

Answers may be whole programs or functions, thus output to STDOUT or return the function result.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply; shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: May we output more than 1 character?

Comment: Does a newline count as a printable character? (I don't think so, just asking for clarification.)

Comment: Do we have to pad the code with spaces so it's a perfect rectangle (and count those spaces in our score)? For example, would code shaped like [this](https://pastebin.com/rjL3vSPP) be valid, given the first one is the submission?

Comment: Apart from the output spec, I think [this is a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/write-a-rectangular-program-that-outputs-the-number-of-times-it-was-rotated)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Output should be a single character.  I originally wanted only `N`, `E`, `S`, `W`, as output but thought perhaps that was too difficult or unnecessarily constraining.

Comment: @BusinessCat You do not have to pad your code to make a rectangle - that example you provided would be valid.

Comment: @ETHproductions New lines aren't printable ASCII to my knowledge.

Comment: @CzarMatt What if our source is 0 or 1 byte(s) long? Is a program like Z acceptable?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Um, how could 4 identical programs print 4 different ASCII chars?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Darn, and here I was searching for examples with "compass" in the q/a.  :)  Also, I was hoping putting this in the sandbox would surface any potential dupes.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma The comment rules make a *big* difference in the two.

Comment: What about trailing whitespace in output, is that ok? Specifically I'm wondering about a single trailing space.

Comment: @CzarMatt Would the score of your example be 13 or 14 bytes if the space on South can be omitted? (i.e. do we count the smallest or the largest rotation?)

Answer (score 23):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
*2
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/L6P9/AA)**

Note that the main entry for a Jelly program is its last link, where any newline character will split links), neither of the two-line programs actually access their top link.

The four full programs, all of which implicitly print their result, are:

[North](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/L6P9/AA):

```
*2   -> (implicit) zero raised to the power of 2 = 0
```

[East](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1@Ly@j/fwA):

```
*
2    -> literal 2 = 2
```

[South](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99I6/9/AA):

```
2*   -> two raised to the power of (implicit) 2 = 4
```

[West](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@IS@v/fwA):

```
2
*    -> (implicit) zero raised to the power of (implicit) zero = 1
```

Comment: This is the final answer. Well done.

Answer (score 21):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
gy
```

Somehow, *somehow*, I found an extremely hacky 2-byte solution...

---

[North](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Z3k=&input=) outputs `0`:

```
gy
```

Since there's no implicit input, it defaults to `0`. `g` on a number returns the sign of the number regardless of its arguments (`"y"` in this case).

---

[East](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Zwp5&input=) outputs `2`:

```
g
y
```

In a multi-line program, the first line sets the input to its result. This is basically a no-op, since `g` on `0` is `0`. Then `y` returns the GCD of `0` and... since it's missing an argument, it defaults to `2` (thanks, [@Oliver](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39035566#39035566)!). This gives `2` as the output.

---

[South](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eWc=&input=) outputs `g`:

```
yg
```

`y`, as before, is GCD. Since **gcd(0, x)** is **x** for any value, `y` on `0` takes the liberty of just returning its argument. In this case, the argument is `"g"`, which is the result.

---

[West](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eQpn&input=) outputs `1`:

```
y
g
```

`y` on 0, as before, returns `2`. This is then passed to `g`, which (as already discussed) is the sign function on numbers. Therefore, the result is `1`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>7309</s> <s>4421</s> 855 bytes

<sup>-2888 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun</sup>
<sup>-3566 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard</sup>

```java
//i/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//n//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.println(0);}}/////
//e//}};)2(nltnirp.tuo.metsyS{)a][gnirtS(niam diov citats{M ecafretni
//r//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//f}/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//a}//
//c;//
//e)//
// 3//
//M(//
//{n//
//sl//
//tt//
//an//
//ti//
//ir//
//cp//
// .//
//vt//
//ou//
//io//
//d.//
// m//
//me//
//at//
//is//
//ny//
//(S//
//S{//
//t)//
//ra//
//i]//
//n[//
//gg//
//[n//
//]i//
//ar//
//)t//
//{S//
//S(//
//yn//
//si//
//ta//
//em//
//m //
//.d//
//oi//
//uo//
//tv//
//. //
//pc//
//ri//
//it//
//na//
//tt//
//ls//
//n{//
//(M//
//1 //
//)e//
//;c//
//}a//
//}f//
///r//
///e//
 //t//
 //n//
 //i//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZI9boUwEIR7TuHSLoLzU3IGKkpEYYFBfgEbmQUJIZ@dkB0ipX/PzSetZ2dnDQ@zmbcwW//ovs9Ta6efOZnWXj99MufJxt60VpTHQoZcK7bgOjEZ52VF0fmhbow6qn0hO@VhpXy@ijR6@a6KlP6yWK1TKtSn9CN5F@ec1pBPlpa9OpRp6uEqUiW9M5PoXNhE665py1EK25o@2qvpcokv2EjrPr3CxSRGW2A/xRBfjFIyDs9YRgYR@lAkx3ARLjPac8YGZVghCYwOd2JiTBZmULoFH3xnyIpRHRiEZNFA2UBZM4aBUSNSg0gGkRSsj9sMG@33RlASPO0dSTDyDuEhWRGeNtxBMreIdD8BBnnz/5XGeyPsIEvGB9oVdi/gktCXeoZG@N//LbvUBHjgmneePw)

[Old version](https://tio.run/##pZgxboQwFET7PYVLKAKbpOQMVJSIwgKDvAGD4IOELM5OkH2E5xJpn8yf@TNoP/rQX/Ni3Kf7u@88tzk7rzx3FGGdmLXXrVGl30SLbdUx205N2rqkktW6oW506qtzEzNl8y7Z8jyU0SXvtLiucAujwImIlSCKgOgJIg0ITRC/AdESRMLH6QKCENQYECVBSEB4/iIbQdiAEIJYuS8WfossICxXBLlz59aaA@Lgs5gJYuLjNAHRcUXQOLeAmAji5Aav@Dh9bDOe4AlB6ICoCKLhy17zQhy4Io4rEuN34PFb8zVruMHRjsRmT7kinitS8R05efyiZld8zTr@rWV5/MZCzAji4IUYx7kTQssVsXwWcdkXbvCV3wLF78bj13NFyoAYubXQixje7NGd39wXKMH7gCh4IV58nNdVpD@JG8XZdclkn7PJyHZWPtVNPTwPpUqc1ZPq7Hyo1oqWzZfKtLpfzfOjF/znIbYZOk9e3Pc/)

Straightforward aproach with comments wrapping the code^2 square, this can be done in pretty much any language.
a (more readable) example in python

```python
##p#####
# r  2 #
print 1#
# n  t #
# t  n #
#4 tnirp
# 3  r #
#####p##
```

Comment: Great general appraoch, now I just need to figure out how to do it! :)

Comment: You can use `interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.println(0);}}` instead to save some bytes.

Comment: [Would this be work? Its way shorter](https://tio.run/##rZKxboQwEET7@wqXdhF8SUq@gYoSUVhgkC9gI1iQkOVvJ9wOkdLfuXnSenZ21vAwm/kIk/WP9uc4tHb6lXPT2uuXz815snNnGiuKuJAh14gtuFaMxnlZ0ux8X9VGxXJfyI5ZWCmbziINXt5VntJfFqt1Srn6kn4g7@YpozVko6VlL6MyddWfRSqld2YUrQubaNw5bYmFsI3pZns2nS7zGzbSukvvcDGJ0eTYTzHEN6OQjOgZy8AgQh@K5BhuhsuE9oyxQRlWSAKjxZ0YGaOFGZRuwQffGbJklBGDkGw2UNZQVoy@Z1SIVCOSQSQF63iZYaP92ghKgqe9IglG1iI8JCvC04Y7SKYGka4nwCBv/r/ScG2EHWTB@ES7wu45XBL6UsfQCP/8326nmgAPPOcdxy8 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: *"straightforward"*, he says. I'd hate to do that by hand.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn it wasn't done by hand c;

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn nah, I made this answer to show this algorithm, the language is irrelevant :3

Comment: Ahhh... after sorting oldest you WERE the first to do this, nice.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 33 bytes

```
##)(##))()()  ((
((  ))##    ()##
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X1lZUwOINTWAUEFBQ4NLQ0NBQVNTWVkBCDSA9H8NDU1NoChYBZiAcFDF/gMA)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 33 bytes

```
##)     ## #
(( ))#)())()
  # ( (
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X1lZUwEElJUVlLk0NBQ0NZU1NTSBiAsopqChoPH/PwA)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 36 bytes

```
#)##     ## #
  (())#)())()
 #   ( (
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X1lTWVkBBICUMpeCgoaGpqayJpDQ0ORSAMloKGj8/w8A)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 38 bytes

```
######  (#
(()()())#))((
       #(  ##
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XxkMFBQ0lLk0NDRBUFNZU1NDg0sBApQ1gFj5/38A)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 41 bytes

```
##(#####(#
(()()())#
##))()((
####((#)#)#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X1lZQxkENJS5NDQ0QVBTWVOZS1lZE8TR4ALLaSiDBP//BwA)

Comment: Holy crap! I was working on one, but I couldn't get anywhere. I thought it would take atleast 30-40 minutes of work to figure something out. This is amazing!

Comment: This is very cool!

Comment: Trying to golf you :P so far have 3 of them working

Answer (score 6):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 17 bytes

```
1/ 3<
vPo</
5} @<
```

Outputs `1`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99QX8HYhqssIN9Gn8u0VsHB5v9/AA)

```
5v1
}P/
 o 
@<3
</<
```

Outputs `x`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/9@0zJCrNkCfSyFfgcvBxpjLRt/m/38A)

```
<@ }5
/<oPv
<3 /1
```

Outputs `5`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/9/GQaHWlEvfJj@gjMvGWEHf8P9/AA)

```
</<
3<@
 o 
/P}
1v5
```

Outputs `3`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99G34bL2MaBSyFfgUs/oJbLsMz0/38A)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
Y'X
```

[North](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Uj3i/38A), [East](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/kkudK@L/fwA), [South](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Qj3y/38A), [West](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/gkudK/L/fwA)

Comment: Impressive, that was quick!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I think `Y'X` will work, but I have to try it still.

Comment: @Riley it does, also it works forward and backwards, `Y'X` is also valid. Still looking for a 2-byte though; none of the 'dot commands' work for it, so I'm doubtful it exists.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I don't think there is a 2 byte solution with the way newlines work. It wouldn't be hard to brute Force though.

Comment: `10` would've worked if they allowed multiple characters for an output ;P.*

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn That was my first thought too.

Comment: [Brute-Forcer v0.3](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9uYKBgYWBwdMehlTH/jUxNDs81MjV1UipU8lbSA2IDID60VclbPdrb5fCiQ@uKD6941LTGq6xSSVf38H5dXSWdSr2w022VQWAy@NBuCA/KOLT@8EyXdJPATJ3Dq/WVnBxdlHRqD22p/f8fAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge, <s>17</s> 13 bytes

I thought Befunge would be fun for a geometrical problem. There is a trivial 4x4 solution akin to others here (I need 3 commands) but I managed a bit better.

*Edit: forgot about newlines*

*Edit 2: realized I could create a cat*

*Edit 3: the cat is dead*

```
2v3
@.v
.  
1@.
```

RIP kitty :<

```
1.@ 2
^._.^
3 @.4
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 45 bytes

```
v////v1//v(((
\(((%>2@0>%(((\
  (((v//3v////v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v0wfCMoMgVhDQ4MrBkio2hk5GNipAlkxXAoKQAqoxBii7P///7qBAA)

To recap the gimmick of lost from the esolangs wiki:

> Lost is a 2-Dimensional language where the instruction pointer starts at a random location, moving in a random direction. Despite this, Lost is still capable of creating completely deterministic programs.

So at first glace, Lost is perhaps not the ideal language for this challenge because of its incredible fragility.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>283</strike> <strike>279</strike> 209 bytes

```c
/////////)pm//
/////////;ua//
main(){//}ti//
puts("N"//sn//
);}///////((//
//////////")//
///"//////W{//
///E//////"///
//)"//////////
//((///////};)
//ns//"S"(stup
//it}//{)(niam
//au;/////////
//mp)/////////
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc0tDgQhDAVgP8eoasXmHQA9dsyK1QQxQUBIAEU4O9sM81f3pe@17rM7NwaukRSA5aapVhmsjywN6MUrUy2ZaSMgR6WYfqaZ312QTNLkr02u5xYHhZ7CMk8c040oY9bglziXmpS@6KsmHL0NSlvNuxuS3BzjDw)

Same old comment trick here, but at least, in C this doesn't get **huuuge** ;)

- -4, thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)!
- fixed `W` direction and -70 (!) bytes thanks to comments by [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

Comment: Do you need any of the four slashes on the right edge right above the gap?

Comment: Hey .. uhm ... I guess, actually ... no. Good catch, thanks :)

Comment: I think you can pack it together quite a bit more tightly by moving each `);}` to the line below, [like so](https://tio.run/##TcwxDsMgDAXQPcfwZA@VD8CcNUuHzoihYgAhARPi7PQ3JChe7Cfb372@zo2hd0kKqtuiqRYM1keWptqLB1Mtmekg1RxBMf26Zn7@KskkTX7aybZf21My2/@zG8EUM1Zv4lxqAn1BeBOO3gbQVrPiwZBkcYwf) (I haven't tested the rotations though)

Comment: Oh, the `W` program in your current setup currently fails because there's an extra `sn` after the actual code. Apparently you can fix this by changing the slash right before the `pm` on the top line to a semicolon.

Comment: uhh ... probably time to delete this and start over :o (first version was a square of slashes, but I **thought** I'd do a "*clever*" thing saving some bytes ... dammit)

Comment: @ETHproductions I fixed/improved it using your very nice idea (don't know why I didn't see it as I **did** experiment with line breaks ...) If you want to post it yourself, that would be fair and I'll delete it.

Comment: It's your answer, I'm just helping you golf it ;-) You can shave off a few more bytes by making the actual code a 3x6 rectangle: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcuxDoAgDATQ3c/oRAfTD2B2dXFwJgyGAUIiTIRvx8MI8bZ3vdr1srY1@ULFiyxDZzSQNy4oxi07qMScbiXCKUC0E@sqons1/2qfT72BWNWf1K0x1EwHQSFxr1KOBXKZ@jw44yETt9@fLzTU2gM)

Comment: Just a nitpick but it looks like you've got two "W"s

Answer (score 4):

## [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 34 bytes

```
  zz  
  +   
   .  
    +
```

Or with spaces shown as hyphens so you can see them:

```
--zz--
--+---
---.--
----+-
------
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fQaGqSkGBS0FBWwFMKehBKCAfTCko/P8PAA)

The commands in Starry are `+`, `.` and some other things, and what they do is determined by how many spaces there are before them: a `+` with *n* spaces pushes *n*−5 to the stack, and `.` with an even number of spaces prints it. The `z`s and newlines are ignored entirely.

There are 6 spaces before the first `+` so it pushes 6−5 = 1, and the `.` prints it.

And the rotations:

```
-----
-----
---+z
--.-z
-+---
-----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fAQS44KR2FZDUUwCS2nDx//8B) This prints "8".

```
------
-+----
--.---
---+--
--zz--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fAQy4FLQhlIIehALxgVRVlYLC//8A) This prints "2".

```
-----
---+-
z-.--
z+---
-----
-----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fAQS4gFhbgatKQQ/IrtKGisDI//8B) And this prints "3".

Comment: What a neat language. Also, I never said you have to pad with whitespace to form a rectangle.  But if your source relies on the spaces then I suppose you have to count them.

Comment: @CzarMatt, thanks for the clarification! I've updated the post.

Answer (score 4):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 9 bytes

```
!
2@2
 !)
```

Prints `0`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fkcvIwYhLQVHz/38A)

```
 2)
 @!
!2
```

Prints `3`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fwUiTS8FBkUvR6P9/AA)

```
)!
2@2
  !
```

Prints `1`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fU5HLyMGIS0FB8f9/AA)

```
 2!
!@
)2
```

Prints `2`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fwUiRS9GBS9Po/38A)

#### Explanation

Each program starts at the first non-space in reading order (i.e. either the top left or top centre character), moving east. For the first program:

```
!   Print an implicit zero.
    The IP can't move east, so it moves south instead.
2   Push a 2.
    The IP can't keep going south, so it turns east instead.
@   Terminate the program.
```

For the second program:

```
2   Push a 2.
)   Increment it to 3.
    The IP can't keep going east, so it turns south instead.
!   Print the 3.
    The IP can't keep going south, so it turns west instead.
@   Terminate the program.
```

For the third program:

```
)   Increment an implicit zero to 1.
!   Print the 1.
    The IP can't keep going east, so it turns south instead.
@   Terminate the program.
```

For the fourth program:

```
2   Push a 2.
!   Print the 2.
    The IP can't keep going east, so it turns back around to move west.
2   Push another 2.
    The IP can't keep going west, so it turns south instead.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), 7 bytes

```
O@$
)))
```

Prints `0`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v/f30GFS1NT8/9/AA)

```
)O
)@
)$
```

Prints `1`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9f059L04FLU@X/fwA)

```
)))
$@O
```

Prints `3`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9fU1OTS8XB//9/AA)

```
$)
@)
O)
```

Prints `2`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9fRZPLQZPLX/P/fwA)

#### Explanation

The first program is easy enough: `O` prints an implicit zero and `@` terminates the program.

Starting at the second program, we need to look at the triangular grid layout to understand the control flow:

[image]

```
)   Increment an implicit zero to 1.
O   Print the 1.
))  Two irrelevant increments.
@   Terminate the program.
```

For the third program:

[image]

```
))) Increment an implicit zero to 3.
O   Print the 3.
@   Terminate the program.
```

The fourth one is where it gets really funky. Dashed lines indicate cells that aren't executed because they are skipped by the `$`:

[image]

```
$   Skip the ).
$   Skip the @.
))  Increment an implicit zero to 2.
O   Print the 2.
))  Two irrelevant increments.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Comment: Super cool, great diagrams, too.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>20</s> 11 bytes

```powershell
#4#
1#3
#2#
```

Abuses comments (`#`) like crazy, and the fact that a single number placed onto the pipeline gets output as-is. The above prints `1`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X9lEmctQ2ZhL2Uj5/38A)

From here, you can easily see that each rotation yields only one number that's on the "left" of the comments, and so there's only one number that will be output per rotation.

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)!*

Comment: Don't know powershell, but wouldn't [this](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X9lImctQ2ZhL2UT5/38A "PowerShell – Try It Online") work?

Comment: @WheatWizard Yes, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), <s>20 17 12</s> 11 bytes

```
.$
Z%"
+$v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/19PhStKVYlLW6WM6/9/AA)

All this time and no-one answered in Cardinal? This first one outputs `0`.

#### East

```
 +Z.
 $%$
 v"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/19BO0qPS0FFVYVLoUzp/38A)

Outputs `1`.

#### South

```
v$+
"%Z
 $.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/5@rTEWbS0k1iktBRe//fwA)

Outputs a space.

#### West

```
 "v
$%$
.Z+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/19BqYxLRVWFSy9K@/9/AA)

Outputs `v`.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 9 bytes

```
 1
2p3
 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/1/BkMuowJhLweT/fwA)

I think its obviousness is part of the charm.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 90 bytes

```
 :: :::@:
:&s ohce@
:e   : c:
      :h:
:o     o:
:h:
:c :   w:
@echo n&:
:@::: ::
```

Batch doesn't really have a comment character. For whole-line comments, `:` works, as it introduces a label, but I still need something to terminate the `echo` command while being a no-op when reversed. `&:` seems to work, which is all I need here, but it really confuses Batch, erroring out if I don't put a `:` before the `@` on the next line, and also somehow forgetting to print a newline.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

Outputs 0 for North, 1 for East, 2 for South, and 3 for West.

```js
////  _//
////  =//
_=>0//>//
  ////1//
  // //
//3////
//>//2>=_
//=  ////
//_  ////
```

```js
const source =
`////  _//
////  =//
_=>0//>//
  ////3//
  // //
//1////
//>//2>=_
//=  ////
//_  ////`;

function rotateTextCW(text) {
  const lines = text.split("\n");
  const maxLineLength = lines
    .map(line => line.length)
    .reduce((max, len) => Math.max(len, max), 0);
  const paddedLines = lines.map(line => line.padEnd(maxLineLength));
  const charGrid = paddedLines.map(line => line.split(""));
  const rotatedGrid = [...new Array(maxLineLength)]
    .map(v => new Array(charGrid.length));

  for (let i = 0; i < charGrid.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < charGrid[i].length; j++) {
      rotatedGrid[j][charGrid.length - i - 1] = charGrid[i][j];
    }
  }

  return rotatedGrid
    .map(chars => chars.join("").trimRight())
    .join("\n");
}

const orientations = ["North", "East", "South", "West"];
let rotatedSource = source;
let markup = "";

orientations.forEach(orientation => {
  const code = `<pre>${rotatedSource}</pre>`;
  const result = `<code>${eval(rotatedSource)()}</code>`;
  const row = `
    <td>${orientation}</td>
    <td>${code}</td>
    <td>${result}</td>`;
  markup += `<tr>${row}</tr>`;
  rotatedSource = rotateTextCW(rotatedSource);
});

document.querySelector("table tr:first-child")
  .parentNode
  .innerHTML += markup;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
    <tr>
      <th>Orientation</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>29 17 5</s> 11 bytes

Having realised that the question called for single ASCII characters not just a distinct output, here is a MATLAB approach which will do just that:

```
%4%
1%3
%2%
```

This will implicitly print 1, 2, 3, or 4 depending on the rotation.

Comment: Come to think of it, this would work in MATL as well. Same byte count as mine, though.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
5H
I
```

Outputs `1`, [Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=NUglMEFJ)

```
I5
 H
```

Outputs `H`, [Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=STUlMEElMjBI)

```
 I
H5
```

Outputs `5`, [Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTIwSSUwQUg1)

```
H
5I
```

Outputs `6`, [Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=SCUwQTVJ)

Comment: If it contains a space, it is 5 bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder OP in comments said that you don't need to pad it

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
HxI
xFx
TxK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36PCk6vCrYIrpML7/38A)

Let's get this started in MATL. The main challenge is that MATL just fails if a function requires input if the stack is empty. Perhaps something clever with modifiers like `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `&` could make for something shorter, but I couldn't find a suitable combination.

Explanation: all characters push a single integer on the stack, and `x` removes all of them but the last.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 49 bytes

**48 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

Assumes empty input which TIO doesn't support, so a newline is added in its place and not used. Prints [N](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19ZQRkIuJSDbRXiVbiUrRXClbkUVOJt/YBi8QrxQNJWQQVIugKFlYGK///n@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cAAA), [E](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19ZRUFZAQi4lOOV/ZSVFZS5lBXCbeNVQCK2CvEKCsrKXArB1irxtq5AKZACIP7/n@tffkFJZn5e8X/dAgA), [S](https://tio.run/##FYkhDoBADAR9X7HJ1iJRpBKLQSCrECQXrgHeTyljJpmJ/WpjJggSAoAzBVTYL4dTuJhrPW6YKOqwtWIBZsrb4zn6eecQHw), [W](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19BWVkZhLmUXW3jVayDFbiAfIV4BVtlLgUFlXjbcAWgFFCBn3I8SERBQVlBRfn/f65/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA).

```pl
# ####
#S= _$
#; W#
 $_=N#
#_ _#
#= $#
#E#
 ## #
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19ZQRkIuJSDbRXiVbiUrRXClbkUVOJt/YBi8QrxQNJWQQVIugKFlYGK///n@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 120 bytes

I had hoped for more synergy between the variants.

```c
//}=)f8 ///
// c{(7 ///
   ;rr; //}
        ;c=
78; /// r{)
f(r /// r(f
){r /// ;38
=c;
}// ;rr;
/// 9({c //
/// 6f)=}//
```

[North](https://tio.run/##Jc0xCsMwDAXQuTqFCBQkaNBQaFyEb9KlCBQy1BTTzfjsru1oevqCL1t3s9ZEamQPKCIgglZom0ZEzVm76/ActQhbGJlgLgxO@TQ5cDmt9wDRFOpwL4ARPqkYzgeCD@fYj@1IP/y8j0QMBS7f3Hen5WqvtNzQibl3tD8)

[East](https://tio.run/##NYzBCgIxDETP5ivCgpCASw6CWwn9Ey8SyLIHixRvpd/era6d0xuGNzavZq2J1Mi@IIqAiFihMFhzVkSsgP@oRbjdtc@CuTA45YPJgcvBugSIpkOB@vX6kfw@Ea9UbHBwjlWkbemDr@eWiKHA6Z17d5rO9kjTBZ2YFWrbAQ)

[South](https://tio.run/##Nc2xCgMxCAbguT6FHBQUWhwKvRTJm3QpguWGhhK6hTx7LslRp89fVLu@zVoTqZH9jiICImiFHtOIqDlrdx2epRYh3EYmmAuDUz5MDlwOa1ghmv5XoI5sHOoe85WK4fwlGJxjn7ct/fDz2hIxFDh9c@@dlrM903JBJ2aF2nY)

[West](https://tio.run/##NYzBCgIxDETP5ivCgpCASw6CWwn9Ey8SyLIHixRvpd/era6d0xuGNzavZq2J1MgeEEVARKzQdbDmrIhYAf9RixAW7bNgLgxO@WBy4HKw3m8QTYcC9ev1I/l9IgYqNnhxjlWkbemDr@eWiKHA6Z17d5rO9kjTBZ2YFWrbAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Þ2Þ
3 1
Þ0Þ
```

A bit boring, but since MathGolf implicitly outputs the entire stack joined together, I'm not sure if something shorter is possible here..

[Default](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wPKPD87iMFQy5Ds8zODzv/38A); [rotated once clockwise](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wPOPD87gMFIy4Ds8zPDzv/38A); [rotated two times clockwise](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wPIPD87gMFYy5Ds8zOjzv/38A); [rotated three times clockwise](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wPMPD87iMFAy4Ds8zPjzv/38A).

**Explanation:**

- `0123`: These push the digit to the stack
- : This pushes a space character to the stack
- `Þ`: This empties the stack except for the top value

And in the end the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 72 bytes

```
++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fW5tLmxDQI6iCS/v/fwA)
[Try it rotated once!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fW1ubSwGMaYn0aGw@CP3/DwA)
[Try it rotated twice!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fgWKgzaVNCOgRVMFFuTO0//8HAA)
[Try it rotated thrice!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fQZuL5kiPtuZrg5D2//8A)

Comment: Nice idea. `<33 copies of +>.<35 copies of +><newline>+` to save a newline, and I think it's the shortest possible that prints those 4 chars.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 69 bytes

```javascript
 _=>0//
/*    *_
/      =
1      >
>      3
=      /
_*    */
 //2>=_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczLCoAgEIXh/TzFLFWo6bIeX0XEJApRSen1LfRffYvDue1ri3uuXKeYDt9ciqViRm5oWC9EQAr/lAHCHsM6oEEP7MADBGaMCZBo02z6Xwp@DukUWUjZPg)

This approach should work for any language with C-style comments.

Answer (score 0):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 5 bytes

### North: 3

```
2M:
2
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=2M%3A%0A2&input=)

### East: 4

```
22
 M
 :
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=2M%3A%0A2&input=)

### South: 2

```
  2
:M2
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=2M%3A%0A2&input=)

### West: 1

```
:
M
22
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=2M%3A%0A2&input=)

The existing 1 in the stack is very convenient here.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 71 bytes

```
##p#####
# r  2 #
print 1#
# n  t #
# t  n #
#4 tnirp
# 3  r #
#####p##
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5RDoAgDEP/OUWTnYDBoeQHCdmPp8ehMCW6r6aU15ZDtj1za0SF@jlCBRjkSk1Z4LuTAUEXAtUqIiSnWtQJ0Lw6/ZTgHkWI4y1Yev6fxLuDR6u/QGOHWxdFS4ffRWwd/rvoDQoGir8gbyBeQa2d)

Big thanks to [this answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137588/cardinal-code-challenge/137618#137618)

Note I **did not** copy it directly, but actually had a program in mind and golfed it with this.